# primeng dropdown error ('p-dropdown' is not a known element)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to use dropdown menu coponent from primeNG for Angular. It works in the template that I'm using, but when I try to make my own it doesn't although I copy-pasted everything from the template.

**frequency.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './frequency.component.html'
})
export class FrequencyComponent {

    selectedState: any = null;

    dropdownItems = [
        { name: 'Option 1', code: 'Option 1' },
        { name: 'Option 2', code: 'Option 2' },
        { name: 'Option 3', code: 'Option 3' }
    ];


}
```

**frequency.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FrequencyComponent } from './frequency.component';
import { FrequencyRoutingModule } from './frequency-routing.module';
import { AutoCompleteModule } from "primeng/autocomplete";
import { CalendarModule } from "primeng/calendar";
import { ChipsModule } from "primeng/chips";
import { DropdownModule } from "primeng/dropdown";
import { InputMaskModule } from "primeng/inputmask";
import { InputNumberModule } from "primeng/inputnumber";
import { CascadeSelectModule } from "primeng/cascadeselect";
import { MultiSelectModule } from "primeng/multiselect";
import { InputTextareaModule } from "primeng/inputtextarea";
import { InputTextModule } from "primeng/inputtext";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        FrequencyRoutingModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        CalendarModule,
        ChipsModule,
        DropdownModule,
        InputMaskModule,
        InputNumberModule,
        CascadeSelectModule,
        MultiSelectModule,
        InputTextareaModule,
        InputTextModule
    ],
    declarations: [FrequencyComponent]
})
export class FrequencyModule { }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Make my own"?

Comment: @CaioOliveira Basically, I took this template https://www.primefaces.org/sakai-ng/#/uikit/menu/personal and I wanted to add my own page to it, I copy pasted the code from "Form Layout"